# Showing 'Failed to load theme' error in wordpress Callisto RocketTheme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I installed the 'WordPress RocketLauncher' in Callisto Theme. It is showing the error 'Failed to load theme:'. Please help me to resolve this.

Version:
Wordpress - 4.3.1
Gantry 5 Framework Plugin - 5.1.5
Timber Plugin - 0.21.10

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upload the theme from the wp-admin appearence->add new->upload you must select your zip, or check the permissions folder, my theme's folder always have 755.

Comment: Actually i installed the WordPress RocketLauncher, so it contains the following:
Version: Wordpress - 4.3.1 Gantry 5 Framework Plugin - 5.1.5 Timber Plugin - 0.21.10